# Windows bat file equivelent of bash string manipulation

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file

How would I achieve this:

```
for i in *.e; do mv $i ${i%-b*.e}.e; done
```

in a Windows batch file? (It renames files containing "-b" to the part before "-b". Note that this is not necessarily the end of the string! e.g. "file-b-4.e" will become "file.e")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, really

```
for %%i in (*-b*.e) do call :ren_b %%~ni
goto :eof
:ren_b
set v=%*
set v="%v:-b=.e" ^& rem %
ren "%*.e" %v%
```

Here's a variant to keep the name till the last `-b` occurence

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*-b*.e) do (
    set v=%%~ni
    set v=!v:-b=\!
    for %%j in ("\!v!") do (
        set v=%%~pj
        set v=!v:~1,-1!
        set v=!v:\=-b!
        ren "%%i" "!v!.e"
    )
)
```

It will fail for names containing `!` and starting with `-b`.

*P.S,* Didn't see, dbenham already provided the equivalent solution, probably with more provisions for terminal cases of file names.

Comment: This does indeed do what I need, but just for reference (if anybody else is ever looking for this), it is not an exact equivalent of the bash command in the question. That removes from the last occurrence, while this is from the first.

Comment: +1, I forgot about the command injection technique. But it's not quite as simple as you think. The code fails if name contains `&` or `^`. I've got a working variant in my updated answer :)

Comment: Added variant for the last occurence of -b

Comment: Your 2nd variant also fails if file name contains back to back -b-b because Windows treats \\ as \ when parsing paths (unless at beginning of path). The last variant in my answer should work with any valid Windows file name. *(This is a corrected version of my prior deleted comment)*

Comment: Doesn't seem as "simple" as the bash equivalent to me!

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to do this in batch, this should work

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*.e) do (
  set "var=%%~F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "var=!var:-b=.e:!"
  for /f "eol=: delims=:" %%A in ("!var!") do (
    endlocal
    echo ren "%%F" "%%A"
  )
)
```

***Edit***
The comment by panda-34 alluded to the fact that the original posted code failed if the file name begins with `-b`. The code above was fixed by incorporating the extension into the replacement string. *(thanks panda-34 for alerting me to the problem)*

panda-34 also provided an alternate solution that uses command injection with search and replace. The injected command is the REM statement.

The panda-34 solution works as long as the file name does not contain `&` or `^` characters, but fails if it does.

Below is a modified version of the command injection technique that should work with all valid Windows file names. There are 2 critical mods, 1) make sure the special chars in the file name are always quoted, and 2) do not pass the value as a CALL argument, otherwise `^` will be doubled to `^^`.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in (*-b*.e) do (
  set old="%%~ni"
  call :ren_b
)
exit /b
:ren_b
set v=%old:-b=.e"&rem "%
echo ren "%old:~1,-1%.e" %v%
exit /b
```

***Final Edit (I hope):***
As baruch indicates in his comment, the solutions above remove starting with the 1st occurance, whereas the original bash command removes starting with the last occurance.

Below is a version that should be an exact equivalent of the original bash command.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "search=-b"
for %%A in (*%search%*.e) do (
  set "old=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "new=\_!old:%search%=\_!"
  for %%B in ("!new!") do (
    endlocal
    set "new=%%~pB"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "new=!new:~2,-1!.e"
    echo ren "!old!" "!new:\_=%search%!"
    endlocal
  )
)
```

Comment: Basically, what I was about to suggest (I used `?` instead of `:`), only your version is better, because I was lazy with mine and decided to go with a subroutine.

Comment: There's one tiny detail I would change, though: `"%%A.e"` -> `"%%A%%~xF"` (so when you need to change the extension, you change it in one place).

Comment: You're positively crazy for writing this up :) ... +1

Comment: @AndriyM - That certainly can't hurt, and might be useful.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED - My wife agrees with you :)  Batch programming happens to be my hobby.

Comment: You seem to have taken for granted that file name cannot start with -b, that was not stated by OP.

Comment: This does indeed do what I need, but just for reference (if anybody else is ever looking for this), it is not an exact equivalent of the bash command in the question. That removes from the last occurrence, while this is from the first.

Comment: @panda-34: Thanks, I've updated the answer to support names starting with `-b`.

Comment: @baruch: I've updated the answer to include a variant that is an exact equivalent of the bash command.

Answer (score 2):

Forget it, some convenient things cannot be done in NT scripting. What you are asking here is not possible to my knowledge. And I've written and maintained complex NT scripts bigger than 50 KiB, using all kinds of tricks. The book "Windows NT Shell Scripting" points out many of these, for the same and more see [Rob van der Woude's scripting pages](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/).

I reckon you could do part of this, but certainly not in a one-liner due to how variable expansion works in NT scripting. For example you could extract the part of the string that you expect to be `-b` and check whether it is `-b`, then extract the other parts and rename from the original name to the one that is comprised of only the extracted parts.

But you'll likely need ten to fifteen lines to achieve that. In that light, consider using a different scripting language for the purpose. Especially if this is a modern Windows version.

I realize this is not the desired answer (i.e. that this is possible and a sample), but `cmd.exe` is very limited compared to Bash, albeit by far not as limited as some opponents of traditional batch scripting are pointing out.

Comment: I particularly like your last sentence.